# Adding all addresses from an account to the address book in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

I recently installed Debian 12 and Thunderbird 102.12.0 from the standard repository. After that I added my Gmail account. When I start typing an email address which I have used previously I get no suggestions. As far as I understand the address has to be in the address book in order to appear as a suggestion (auto complete). Is there a way to collect all email addresses from old mails and add them to the address book?

Comment: I don't have your  setup up so there may be a better solution out there. However, the tool located https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/ is supposed to be able to export all emails to an HTML file. If you were to do this, you could then do some regex commands to select and delete anything that doesn't have an @ sign. From there you could aggregate and delete duplicates.

Comment: According to a solution here, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1154012, you should be able to import email addresses if they are in .csv file.

Comment: There appears to be a paid solution here, https://www.bitrecover.com/blog/thunderbird-email-address-extractor/. I am not associated with this website and cannot speak to its effectiveness.

Comment: For exporting the list, you can use the Google Contacts (Other Contacts) https://contacts.google.com/other, and then import with the method @Brian pointed to

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 to Export Contacts (Gmail)

---

**Export contacts**

To add your contacts to another email account, first download them as a CSV or vCard file. To clear up storage, export and then delete contacts you don't need.

1. Go to Google Contacts.
2. Select one of the following:

   -A single contact: Check the box next to the contact name.

   -Multiple contacts: Check the boxes next to all the contacts you want to export.

   -All contacts: Check the box next to any contact and in the top left, click Selection Actions and then All.
3. At the top right, click More actions and then Export.
4. To back up your contacts, select Google CSV.
5. To save your file, click Export.

   -After you export your contacts, learn how to delete contacts you don’t need.

Tip: If you use Google Contacts for work or school, you can’t select all contacts in the Directory.

source: https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/7199294?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop
Thanks to @Yisroel Tech

---

### Method 2 to Extract Contacts (more complicated; doesn't require Gmail)

---

1. Download ImportExportTools for Thunderbird at https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/
2. From the Tools menu, export all emails to a single, plaintext file.
3. Open plaintext file in an editor that uses regex (e.g. VS Code).
4. Write REGEX that selects non-email text. (unfortunately after a little off-the-cuff testing, this will prove to be a more complicated task that I originally had though it to be. A unique script will probably need to be written to pull out each email address)
5. Delete non-email text.
6. Clean-up file so there is only one email address per line
7. Save as CSV file.

---

### Import Addresses to Thunderbird

---

In Thunderbird, open the Address Book and click on "Tools" in the menu, then "Import".

Select "Address Books" and click "Next". Select "Text file (LDIF, .tab, .csv, .txt)" and click "Next".

In the "Select address book file" window, just above the "Open" and "Cancel" buttons on the bottom right, change the file type to "Comma Separated (*.csv)". Then navigate to where you saved the .csv file you exported from Excel, choose it, and click "Open".

Now you will get an "Import Address Book" window where you will need to match up Thunderbird address book fields with the fields that are in your .csv file. Check mark the fields you want, and move them up or down to match the fields in your .csv file. When done matching, click "OK".

That will create a new address book with the name of the .csv file.

source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1154012

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.